# How to compare tables?

Tags: java, arrays

In the code below, I count number of Strings then try to check that number match values
the code is correct but I don't know how to compare a matrix with a counted value:

For example : counter 1 gives:

```
10
150
10
0
200
```

and I need to check that that's match values?

```
int[][] values = { { 10, 150, 10, 0, 10, 200 }, { 20, 5, 18, 60, 14, 0 }, { 16, 5, 18, 20, 25, 30 } };

for (int i = 1; i < 4;i++)
    {    
      //do action here
      int counter1 = 0;
      int counter2 = 0;
      int counter3=0;
      int counter4=0;
      int counter5=0;
      int counter6=0;   

      for (int j = 0; j < myTableNbRows; i++)
      {
        if (myTable.getValue(j, 0).matches("hello"))
        {
          if (myTable.getValue(j, 1).contains("tions."))
          {
            counter1++;
          }
        if (myTable.getValue(j, 1).contains("ons."))
          {
            counter2++;
          }
     if (myTable.getValue(j, 1).contains("an."))
          {
            counter3++;
          }
      if (myTable.getValue(j, 1).contains("auns."))
          {
            counter4++;
          }
    if (myTable.getValue(j, 1).contains("896."))
          {
            counter5++;
          }
     if (myTable.getValue(j, 1).contains("1222."))
          {
            counter6++;
          }

        }
      }
//here I nedd to compare values with counter 
 assertEquals(values,counter1);
 assertEquals(values,counter2);
```

....

Comment: Can you give a example of what you mean by "compare values with counter" ? I am assuming for example whether the value of counter1 is somewhere in the array "values" !?

Comment: I need to use assertEquals to verify value==counter

Comment: Tip: fix indentation to make the code structure easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options...
Store your counters in a array and call the assert in a loop

```
for (int t = 0; t<counters.length; t++) {
   assertEquals(values[i][t], counters[t]);
}
```

Another option is to use Hamcrest Matchers. For example, IsArrayContainingInOrder.

[IsArrayContainingInOrder](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/IsArrayContainingInOrder.java?r=561)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4;i++)
{    
  //do action here
  int[] counters = new int[6];

  for (int j = 0; j < myTableNbRows; i++)
  {
    if (myTable.getValue(j, 0).matches("hello"))
    {
      if (myTable.getValue(j, 1).contains("tions."))
      {
        counters[0]++;
      }
    ...
    ...
    }

   for (int t = 0; t<counters.length; t++) {
     assertEquals(values[i][t], counters[t]);
   }
   // or preferred method
   assertThat(counters, IsArrayContainingInOrder.arrayContaining(values[i]));
}
```

Comment: Where your current **assertEquals** are located. Just put your counters in an array so you can loop over them.

Comment: as follow ? int[]counter ={0,0,0,0,0,0} ;for (int t = 0; t<5; t++{
   assertEquals(values[i][t], counters[t]);
}

Comment: see java.util.Arrays#deepEquals() and #equals()

Comment: @Ustaman: true but I would prefer to use Hamcrest where possible for assertions. Hence, IsArrayContainingInOrder

Comment: @lola - yes, with you incrementing the counters in the array rather than individual fields. But the syntax would be **int[] counters = new int[6];** Array is auto-initialized to all 0's.

Comment: could you please, tell me how using it ?

Comment: @lola yes (but you want `int[] counters=...` with an 's'), and you also want to replace `counter1++` with `counters[0]++` and similarly for counter2, etc. Also instead of `t<5` you should do `t<counters.length`. And remember the closing parenthesis after `t++`.

Comment: Kevin,john : I tried as you have mentioned : but counter shows always 0 ?

Comment: inside for(int j = 0; j < myTableNbRows; j++), I increment counter[0]++ in each if block , after closing for ;  I add :
for (int t = 0; t < counters.length; t++)
      {
        System.out.println("expected"+values[i - 1][t]);
        System.out.println("counters"+counters[t]);

Comment: I don't undestand why do counters[0]++ is 0?

Comment: @John, could you help me please ?

Comment: You current have 6 counters (counter1 - counter6). This is replaced with an array (counters). Since arrrays are 0-indexed, counters[0] equates to counter1, counters[1] => counter2, etc. So everywhere in your code you had counter1++, I put counters[0]++. You would do the rest of the replacements for counters2-6.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at the

```
Character.toString()
```

method.

Comment: Please explain how this will help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `values` actually represents, but assuming it should be a defined set of counts that need to be matched (i.e. you have `(counter1==10 AND counter2==150 ...) OR (counter1==20 AND counter2==5 ...) ...`), then try something like this:

```
boolean matchFound = false;
for( int[] valuesRow : values ) {
   matchFound = valuesRow[0] == counter1 && valuesRow[1] == counter2 ...;
   if( matchFound) {
     break;
   }
}
```

Note that generally, you should make a `counter` array: `int[] counter = new int[6];` and increment the array contents. Then you can loop over the values rows as shown above but compare the elements in another row:

```
boolean matchFound = false;
for( int[] valuesRow : values ) {
   boolean rowMatches = true; //assume a match
   for( int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++ ) {
     if( valuesRow[i] != counters[i] ) {
       rowMatches = false;
       break; //break the inner loop
     }
   }
   if( rowMatches ) {
     matchFound = true;
     break; //the outer loop
   }
}
```

As a side note: you could also use loop labels and directly continue the outer loop once you found a non-matching value.

Edit: rereading your code, I realized you have 4 value arrays and loop through 4(?) datasets/tables.

However, there are some issues:

1. `for (int j = 0; j < myTableNbRows; i++)` you're incrementing `i` and not `j` as I assume would be correct
2. You need to call the assert in that loop since outside `counter1` etc. is not visible.

That said, have your asserts like this (in the inner loop):

```
assertEquals(values[i-1][0], counter1); //note that you loop i from 1 to 4 so you need to subtract 1 (array indices are 0 to 3)
assertEquals(values[i-1][1], counter2);
...
```

Edit2: 
If you want to do the asserts after your outer loop, you need to make counter a 2-dimensional array: `int[][] counter = new int[4][6];` and increment like this: `counter[i-1][j]++;` (note the `i-1` as described above). Then loop over `values` and `counter` and compare.